# Error reading local file in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm trying to write a Sinatra app that reads in a list from a file, and then spits back a random item from that list.

I'm having trouble figuring out the path to the file to read it, though. Sinatra says 'no such file or directory' when I try to load an item in my browser:

```
Errno::ENOENT at /wod
No such file or directory - http://localhost:4567/listing.txt
```

Here is the code:

```
require 'sinatra'

@list

get /item
  puts read_list[rand(@list.size)]
end

def read_list
  File.open('listing.txt', 'r').readlines
end
```

I have the file in `/public`, which the Sinatra README says is the default location for hosting static files. Furthermore, if I put it in `/public` I can navigate to `localhost:4567/listing.txt` and read the file in the browser.

Comment: Why is `@list` sitting by itself? Your code sample won't pass a syntax check so it needs to reflect your true code.

Answer (score 3):

A couple things I noticed:

```
get /item
```

isn't correct, it should be:

```
get '/item' do
```

If you start your code inside the same directory the Ruby code is in, the current working-directory will be `"."`, which is where Ruby will look when trying to:

```
File.open('listing.txt', 'r').readlines
```

Ruby will actually use `'./listing.txt'` as the path. That's OK if you manually launch the code from the root directory of the application, but that doesn't work well if you try to launch it from anywhere else.

It's better to be explicit about the location of the file when you're actually trying to load something for use with a web server. Instead of relying on chance, there are a couple things you can do to help make it more bullet-proof. Consider this:

```
def read_list
  running_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
  running_dir = Dir.pwd if (running_dir == '.')
  File.open(running_dir + '/public/listing.txt', 'r').readlines
end
```

[`File.dirname`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-dirname) gets the path information from `__FILE__`, which is the absolute path and name of the current file running. If the application was started from the same directory as the file, that will be `.`, which isn't what we want. In that case, we want the absolute path of the current working-directory, which [`Dir.pwd`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-pwd) returns. Then we can append that to the path of the file you want, from the root of the application.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to do `File.read('public/listing.txt', 'r')` to get what you want here.

`File.open` isn't part of Sinatra and doesn't know to look in a specific place for static files, so it just looks in the current working directory.